# Numeric Values only

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Numeric validation with RegExp to prevent invalid user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825672/numeric-validation-with-regexp-to-prevent-invalid-user-input)

I am new to regex. I wish to write a pattern for numeric values only (for JavaScript).

1. numeric values only.
2. allowed decimal "."
3. no commas.

Comment: Are you trying to match decimal numbers or IP address like sequences of digits and periods?

Comment: @anubhava it matches an empty string.

Comment: Is it allowed to have no digit before the decimal point? Is it allowed to have leading zeros, e.g. 0001? Your requirements are not sufficient. And we love to **help** writing a regex, but your question is more "write the regex for me"

Comment: You could just see if you get a valid number out of `parseFloat` ? Sure it will get a valid number out of "`34.4134asd"` (`34.4134`) but does that matter ?

Comment: In future, please edit new information your original question, please don't ask what amounts the same question in a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825672). Question repetition does go down favourably on our site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [great resource](http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-validate2.php) for playing around with various regular expressions in JavaScript. Your particular expression looks like this:

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: thanks! how would I update the regex if I need to allow one comma and the number to be only positive?

Comment: @ihtus something like this would probably do: `/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: @anubhava, Question doesn't tell is it valid number or not...

Comment: Question doesn't tell it clearly but `.28` and `.15` are all valid numeric values indeed.

Comment: @anubhava, It depends on UI design, business-logic, ect. Are you mind-reader?

Comment: No sir, it's not about anybody's mind. As per arithmetic `.28`, `.59`, `-.5` and `.15` are all valid numeric values.

Comment: @anubhava, `0.28` like `.28` like `0x10` are only string representations of number.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a RegEx and taking care of all permutations of a float number, I would suggest following code to check if it is a valid float number:

```
var s = ".45";
var d = parseFloat(s);
if (!isNaN(d))
   alert("valid float: " + d);
```

If you have to have a regex then I would suggest:

```
/^[-+]?(?=.)\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: thanks! how would I update the regex if I need to allow one comma and the number to be only positive?

Comment: For that you can simply use: `/^\+?(?=.)(?:\d+,)?\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example here for floating point number regex samples...

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html