# Regex for number or float

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for any number OR float.
I have used this but doesn't work:

```
/(^[0-9]+*[.][0-9]+)$|^[\d+]$/
```

Why ?

Comment: `+*` - use `+` or `*` not both in this context

Comment: done but doesn't work.

Comment: Is it validation, or search? it's important to know if you need to match start/end or not

Comment: Explain `I have used this but doesn't work`

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825672/numeric-validation-with-regexp-to-prevent-invalid-user-input), does it solve your issue?

Comment: what do you expect [^\d+] is doing?

Comment: Actually, the only issue you have is the `+` in the `[\d+]` => `\d+`. But you should just use `/^\d*\.?\d+$/` for simple floats and integers as whole strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^[+-]*[0-9]+[.][0-9]+|[+-]*[0-9]+$/g
```

You can use http://www.regexr.com/ to test and create regexes

Comment: Don't need to escape anything in a set, [.] will do

Comment: Thanks, @LukeTO'Brien I did not know

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

In case this might help you. This online Regex Tools is actually very helpful:
http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your regex:

1. You cannot have a quantifier after `+` so change `+*` to just `+` (1 or more matches)
2. Move your start identifier `^` outside of the group, for consistency
3. hmmm, you seem to have edited your regex: but `[^\d+]` was looking for NOT a number or `+` symbol.

One possible solution would be as follows:

```
^([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)$|^\d+$
```

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/eZ3gP0/1)

For more example, [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You expression doesn't work because it contains errors.
[This is the website I use for RegEx testing](http://regexr.com/) - It is good to test them on a website like this that gives you feedback

You have the beginning inside a capturing group, but the end outside - (^...)$

You also have double operators - +* - Use only one

And the or not plus sign and digit is not needed - ?[^\d+]

I believe this expression will do what you want: `^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$`