# Assistance needed with my JavaScript RegExp for my salary income

Tags: javascript

I can get it to only allow numbers only but I need help with:

1. Only the first number can be bigger than 0
2. The user can enter a maximum of 9 characters and a minimum of 2 characters, then they must enter a decimal point.
3. After the decimal they must only enter 2 more numbers.

   ```
   $("#mytextbox").on("keypress", function(event) {

       var ValidPrice = /[1-9][0-9]/;
       var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

       if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || ValidPrice.test(key)) {
           return true;
       }

       return false;
   });

   $('#mytextbox').on("paste",function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

Comment: Have you tried not using regex where it doesn't belong? `<input type="number" min="0" max="999999999.99" step="0.01" />`

Answer (score 1):

To force a number larger than 0, your first part, `[1-9]` should work.

For two to nine characters (or one through eight excluding the first digit), you can use `[0-9]{1,8}` or `\d{1,8}`.

For a decimal point, use `\.`.

For two more numbers, use `\d{2}`.

So to add these together, `/[1-9]\d{1,8}\.\d{2}/` should work.

However, you could also achieve similar functionality by avoiding using Regex altogether - [this answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651044/2465599).

Comment: think it should be `/[1-9]\d{1,8}\.\d{2}/`, otherwise `1111111111.10` is a valid match which has 10 digits before decimal point.

Comment: @Donald I have tried your'e solution, however I am now unable to type anything into the textbox. Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fn9cy/557/, could you please take a look at it just to see if I am going wrong some where?

Comment: @ParandeepSingh I took a look at your JSFiddle, and what's happening is that every time a key is pressed, it is validating that key against the Regex - the Regex if for the full string, i.e. `10.99`, so just pressing `1` and then validating against the Regex will cause it to fail. I'm sure there's a way you could get this to work using JavaScript and a regex but I'd recommend you try achieving the same thing using `type`, `min`, `max` and `step` keywords on the `<input>` tag itself and avoiding the JS solution altogether.

Comment: If you wanted to continue to continue the JavaScript approach, it might be easier to validate the input after the user has entered an input, such as: http://jsfiddle.net/hL4twnsp/. [Here's another similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825672/numeric-validation-with-regexp-to-prevent-invalid-user-input)